# Development of reliable and simple network backup software

Tags: algorithm, network-programming, backup, cloud-storage

**Are there any time proven strategies, algorithms and open-source data storage formats which would be useful to develop reliable and fast incremental backup software for slow network drives?**

I intend to use Qt framework or .NET (not decided yet), but programming language does not matter much because I'm looking for ideas and solutions and not code (although it would be nice to have SDKs or libraries).

I do not intend to create and enterprise level client-server solution, but something simple but still tweakable to my needs.

The long story:

I have been trying to find reliable backup software which supports at least simple obfuscation for both data and filenames (XOR encryption would be fine for me) and also is able to enumerate and extract individual files from the backup archive.

I would like to backup to emulated network drives (using Expandrive or NetDrive).

I have tried many different programs but each of them has at least one critical flaw. Some programs are too slow to back-up to network drives because of complex algorithms. Some programs compress everything to a big zip or custom format file, which can be split into parts but if I try to enumerate and extract individual files it usually ends up with timeouts. Some programs encrypt file contents, but leave file names completely open, without even obfuscating them.

I have tried also some dedicated programs which backup directly to cloud services, but they were to simplified or did not provide any encryption for Google Drive, which I intend to use mostly.

That's why I decided to create something custom which I can tweak to my liking. This would be also an opportunity for me to learn how to implement backup process right.

Currently my idea is to split my backup into some kind of small (100MB ? 50MB ? not sure yet...) sequentially numbered buckets (folders). I can store a lock file in the bucket which is currently in progress. If backup process is interrupted and restarted, I can check if the lock file exists, and then I know that I have to restart that bucket from scratch.

With this bucket system, I'd have to ensure that each bucket has complete files. It means that if I store a 1GB file, I cannot split it into more parts because this would make things really complicated with custom file addressing tables etc. So, my bucket size is just a recommended target but not something strict.

Another concern is how to store list of files and their modification times, so I can implement time-stamp based incremental backups and load the list as fast as possible. I'm not sure if it is good idea to store the file list of each bucket inside that bucket. Maybe it would be better to store it in a single file so I can download it at once? But then I might corrupt that filelist and I won't be able to restore it. Therefore it seems better to store file lists in buckets themselves, but I'm not sure if I'm not missing something.

For encryption, as I said, simple XOR would be fine for me, but if I need something better (and more resource-hungry), I could add some AES - there are lots of libraries out there for this task. I would want to encrypt also file lists. But I'm not sure what should I do with files - should I encrypt each of them individually or should I encrypt entire bucket?

What I'm most concerned about is reliability. How do I check if files in the archive are not corrupted? Corruption is one of the reasons I'm storing he archive in buckets. If data gets corrupted, only one or more of the buckets will be corrupted. But how to detect the corruption? I could calculate checksums, but I'm not sure how to do it fast and what should I calculate them for - individual files? Entire buckets? And what algorithm to use to avoid backup process getting too slow because of calculating checksums?

I could implement deduplication as follows. During backing-up, I have both lists of files (server and local) in memory. If I encounter two occurrences of a filename, I can do checksum to see if they are the same, and if they are, I store the file only in one bucket, but in the filelist of the second bucket I mark that the file is duplicate of the other file which is stored in the first bucket, and when restoring from the archive, I can extract that single file and copy it to both places.

All of these questions lead me to a heretical idea - maybe I could use git?

But I doubt that it is a good tool for backing up 100GB of data. At least, I might learn some useful tricks from git, but again I'm not sure which ideas would or wouldn't work for backup purposes.

If anyone has worked on a similar implementation, it would be great to hear about your experience and maybe some ideas and warnings for ideas which seem intuitively right but might turn out bad in practice.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very ambitious goal of creating a very versatile secure backup system. And while you could very well accomplish exactly what you're looking to do, it could take exponentially longer than expected, as each piece individually, like XORing data and filenames, could be very time consuming to vet, and errors in logic could come at the expense of losing valuable data along the way.

A suggestion is to re-evaluate all existing commercial options available, determine how close they are to the exact needs, like 80%, 70%, 90%...and then ask "is the remaining X% that the commercial tools do not have worth the massive amount of man-hours and possible data loss I'll incur to not only reinvent the 70%,80%,90% available elsewhere, but also to add the remaining X%." Or, would it be easier to reach out to a vendor and say "Hey, let's work together to get your tool do to X% more. I'd love to be a beta tester."

There are companies out there that spend many man-hours developing and testing commercial products which have been vetted over many years. While rolling your own solution, sometimes its also good to support the existing commercial software vendors who do data encryption, zipping, hashing, obfuscating, etc, as a full-time job. Leverage their experience and work with them to achieve a great solution.